# Управление устройством через COM-порт в Windows

Tags: com-порт

Здравствуйте. Есть некое устроиство, которое подключается к компьютеру через COM-порт. Протокол обмена информацией устройства требует, чтобы ID команды отправлялось с битом четности Mark, а тело команды с битом четности Space. Готовые компоненты для работы с COM-портом требуют реконфигурации порта. Из-за этого возникают задержки между ID и телом команды. Соответственно устройство не воспринимает команды, как следует. Под DOS написать такую программу не проблема, там можно управлять регистрами порта напрямую, а вот Windows не позволяет этого делать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо написать свой драйвер, который будет управлять COM-портом, как нужно. А вот прикладная программа будет видеть устройство и отдавать ему команды в понятной форме. [пример драйвера](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Serial-73a4564d).

Answer (score 0):

Это ведь всего один вызов API - SetCommState. Все должно мгновенно происходить.

Еще можно попытаться задать длину байта в 9 бит, а контроль четности аппаратно - отключить. Ну и самостоятельно следить за четностью.

Насчет установки длины байта - в статье [MSDN о DCB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx) написано, что такую длину байта (9 бит) задать нельзя, однако в статье о самой [SetCommState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) говорится, что это ограничение относится только к чипу 8250.